# How to suppress output filename in FFMPEG video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following command line parameters to create a 5 second video from a single png file.  The video contains the output filename near the bottom of the video.  I would like to suppress the filename from the video but everything I have tried so far has not worked.

It is probably something very simple, but it eludes me.

Can someone tell me what I need to add or subtract from this command line to make it just produce the video without the text in it.

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img001.png -c:v libx264 -t 5 -pix_fmt yuvj444p out.mp4

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's your player, not `ffmpeg`. Assuming you're using VLC you can disable or modify the *On Screen Display* (OSD) to prevent this behavior. As of VLC 3.0.4 on Linux:

```
Tools → Preferences → Subtitles/OSD → Uncheck "Show media title on video start" → Save
```

[image]